# I can't connect to a websocket server as a client in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, server, socket.io

I try to connect but it never ends up connecting. It doesn't show me any error, am I putting in the wrong place the data? Do I have to configure something in Unity?

I'm using SocketIoClient c# for the client. The server uses laravel and PHP

I suspect that I'm setting wring the SocketIOOptions. Already tried other 2 plugins, and none of them worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIOClient;

class Program : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Program instance = null;
    async void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("start code");

        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        await Main();
    }

    public async Task Main()
    {
        Debug.Log("start main");

        var uri = new Uri("ws://ws.testing.bet:6781");

        var socket = new SocketIO(uri, new SocketIOOptions
        {
            ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            Query = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"key", "12356"},
                {"cluster", "mt1"},
                {"forceTLS", "true"},
                {"enabledTransports", "ws,wss"}
            },
        });;

        socket.OnConnected += Socket_OnConnected;
        socket.OnPing += Socket_OnPing;
        socket.OnPong += Socket_OnPong;
        socket.OnDisconnected += Socket_OnDisconnected;
        socket.OnReconnectAttempt += Socket_OnReconnecting;
        socket.OnError += Socket_OnError;
        socket.OnAny((name, response) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(name);
            Debug.Log(response);
        });
        socket.On("RealTimeEvent", response =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Message: " + response.GetValue<string>());
        });

        await socket.ConnectAsync();
        Debug.Log("TRYING");
    }

    private static void Socket_OnReconnecting(object sender, int e)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now} Reconnecting: attempt = {e}");
    }

    private static void Socket_OnError(object sender, string e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + e);
    }

    private static void Socket_OnDisconnected(object sender, string e)
    {
        Debug.Log("disconnect: " + e);
    }

    private static async void Socket_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket_OnConnected");

        var socket = sender as SocketIO;
        Debug.Log("Socket.Id:" + socket.Id);

        await socket.EmitAsync("hi", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private static void Socket_OnPing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ping");
    }

    private static void Socket_OnPong(object sender, TimeSpan e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pong: " + e.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does code ever displays "TRYING"?  Is server running with same port number?  To get list of connection use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give list of UDP and TCP ports.  You can have only one connection with same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  Connection will fail if a connection already exists with the three parameters.

Comment: Thank you for helping! it never displays "TRYING". So my best guess is that it never even connected. The server is running with the same port number. How is that of "cmd.exe >Netstat -a"? I'm sorry, i'm new with this, still got a lot to learn.

Comment: Okay, I did the command and i'm not connected to the port 6781. It does not even appear

Comment: You may be getting an exception.  Put a break point on the connect statement to make sure you are getting to the statement.  Netstat displays all the current UDP and TCP ports.  WS protocol uses TCP for the transport layer of the connection.  If connection exists (or attempting to connect) you will see an entry for port 6781.

Comment: It stops at the statement, but the port does not show in the command, why can this be?

Comment: It should show that it is attempting to connect for approximately 30 seconds (the default timeout). I suspect ws has an exception.  I would look at the Event Viewer on machine and see if there are any exceptions.  Also see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket

Comment: What version of Net/Core is your target?  For Core see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0